# Backpropagation with Momentum using Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, backpropagation, momentum

I'm trying to use Scikit-Learn's Neural Network to classify my dataset using a Backpropagation with Momentum. I need to specify these parameters: Hidden neurons, Hidden layers, Training set, Learning rate and Momentum. 
I found MLPClassifier in Sklearn.neural_network package. The problem is that this package is part of Scikit-learn V0.18 which is a dev version.

Is there a way I could use Scikit-Learn V0.17 to do this?

Using Anaconda, but I can change that if it causes problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody ever needs an answer for this, I actually decided to run everything on a Linux VM. I then followed the instructions to install the dev version and everything(well almost) worked perfectly. Running it on Linux is way easier than Windows because you can just install the package from git and run it without having to download required software to compile it. I still struggled a little bit though.

Comment: Could you please give me an example how you implemented Backpropagation

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). They provide an environment that can import the Scikit-Learn toolkit.